# Монітор до комп'ютера українською

Tags: вибір-слова, іншомовні-слова

Ввівши в СУМі слово [монітор](http://sum.in.ua/s/monitor), був здивований, що у нього були такі значення як:

> 1. Баштовий броньований військовий корабель із великокаліберною артилерією, призначений для операцій біля морських берегів і на
>      річках. У складі дніпровської флотилії був монітор «Вірний». Цей
>      корабель гідно боровся з ворогами в роки громадянської війни (Семен
>      Скляренко, Орл. крила, 1948, 12).
> 2. Те саме, що гідромонітор.

Однак жодне з цих слів не підійде для значення: "електронний пристрій для відображення інформації" (див. [Вікіпедію](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)). Отож, як бути із комп'ютерним монітором? Чи є в українській мові якісь відповідники? Адже на Словотворі найкращим варіантом є "візор", однак такого слова в СУМі немає.

Comment: СУМ-11 - словник 80-х років, тобто часів СРСР. Тоді всю комп'ютерну термінологію намагалися з англійської перекладати на російську/українську. Наприклад CD-ROM називався офіційно КД-ПЗП - "компакт-диск - постійно запам'ятовуючий пристрій". А абревіатуру слова "принтер" не згадаю, але там було в кінці "друкувальний пристрій".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***УСЕ (Універсальний словник-енциклопедія)***

> ***[МОНІТОР](http://slovopedia.org.ua/29/53404/15992.html)*** пристрій для відтворення зображення на екрані
> (люмінесцентному або рідкокристалічному) з відеосигналу телекамери,
> комп'ютера, вимірювальних пристроїв.

Найповніше значення даного слова знаходимо в ***Великому тлумачному словнику (ВТС) сучасної української мови***

> ***[МОНІТОР](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53404/908218.html)*** -а, ч. 1. Прилад для контролю станів об'єкта за певними
> параметрами, які повинні зберігатися в заданих межах.
>
> 2. Пристрій для контролю якості телевізійного зображення; відеоконтрольний пристрій.
> 3. Баштовий броньований військовий корабель із великокаліберною артилерією, призначений для операцій біля морських берегів і на
>    річках.
> 4. Те саме, що гідромонітор.
> 5. спец. *Пристрій комп'ютера, призначений для виводу на екран текстової та графічної інформації; дисплей.*
> 6. спец. Машинна програма, яка регулює, контролює або перевіряє операції в системі обробки даних. Монітор реального часу — керівна
>    програма, призначена для організації роботи системи реального часу.
> 7. У мовах програмування – високорівневий механізм взаємодії та синхронізації процесів і керівництва системою.

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/monitor) є приклад ***відображувач***, яке присутнє в СУМ-20

> ***[ВІДОБРАЖУВАЧ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=13236&page=433)***  а, ч. Той, хто щось відображує.

На мою думку, можна використовувати слово ***відображувач*** та ***монітор***, оскільки обидва слова присутні в академічних виданнях.